# knockout.js out of browser testing and faking out the window

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js, qunit

I'm trying to write unit tests for my view models, the view models have a heavy dependency on knockout.js. I'm also using js.net to run the qUnit tests from the microsoft test runner in visual studio. This way when the tests fail I can cancel a build.

I can get simple tests to run but as soon as I load up knockout.js I get a "ReferenceError: window is not defined(knockout-1.3.0beta.js, line 5)" Obviously the window is not defined when I am not running the tests from the browser. However I am only testing view models the window interaction is irrelevant to my tests. Is there anyway I can "fake" or "mock" out the window so that I can use knockout.js in a browserless environment.

Comment: It's a noble goal, I tried using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org), but gave up in the end

Comment: @NickL we went and got the source for knockout and added the files one by one and did some modification, but now we have it running. Basically we made a build with no dependency on window.

Comment: I'd be too scared to modify the source just for tests for fear of breaking something and not realising. A window-less knockout would be good, as I only want to test the view-model logic, not the DOM manipulation. Well done for getting it working though! Perhaps you can post the modified source somewhere?

Comment: @NickL although it is not ideal, we only use the modified source for doing the unit tests, we run against the latest full build for normal use.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure if there is a short-cut solution but normally in such circumstances you need to have a headless browser to test. Because Knockoutjs is tightly integrated to the DOM and Events, I expect you'll need to have a framework which can mock the whole browser structure.

[Zombie.js](http://labnotes.org/2010/12/30/zombie-js-insanely-fast-full-stack-headless-testing/) is one. It requires Node.js to setup but is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of phantomJS and Jasmine to test your KnockoutJS view models. The end result is something like this, its amazing how fast phantom is:

```
$ phantomjs run_jasmine_test.coffee TestRunner.html
 Starting...

 Finished
 -----------------
 1 spec, 0 failures in 0.013s.

 ConsoleReporter finished
```

The basic steps:

- Using [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/), write a spec for your code
- Create a test runner file, add lines for each of your spec files
- Run [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and instruct it to read the test runner.

For more details and step by step instructions, check out a [blog post](http://kylehodgson.com/2012/11/29/knockoutjs-and-testing/) I wrote recently on the subject.